# cs50 pset2 Vigenere cipher

Tags: c, cs50, vigenere

I am getting difficulties to solve Vigenere cipher in problem set2. I have almost done. When I first run the command `./vigenere ABC` with plaintext: `HELLO`, it gives me write answer (ciphertext): `HFNLP`. But when I execute `./vigenere bacon` with plaintext: `Meet me at the park at eleven am`, it doesn't give me the right answer.

Code:

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
     string kword = argv[1];

    if(argc !=2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./vigenere k \n");

        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0, n = strlen(kword); i<n; i++)
        {
            if(!isalpha(kword[i]))
             {
                printf("Usage: ./vigenere k \n");
                return 1;
             }
        }  

    }
    int keylen = strlen(kword);

     printf("Enter Plain Text:\n");

    string p = get_string();

      if (p != NULL)
      {
          for (int i = 0, j = 0, n = strlen(p); i<n; i++)

          {    
           if(isalpha(p[i]))
            {
                 if (islower(p[i]))
              {
                 printf("%c",((p[i] - 97) + (j % keylen) % 26) + 97);
                 j++;
              }
              else if (isupper(p[i]))
              {
                 printf("%c", ((p[i] - 65) + (j % keylen) % 26) + 65);
                j++;
              }

            }  
             else
              printf("%c", p[i]);

      }

    printf("\n");
}

 return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Just letting you know, there is a `CS50` stack exchange.

Comment: "i need help to find out the Problems". That's what a debugger is for. Step thru your code in the debugger and examine its running state.

Comment: You are not using `kword` for encryption.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)